# Ninject and MVC Scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, t4, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am trying to customise MVC Scaffolding T4 template for Repository so that it creates Ninject bindings in my App_Start\NinjectMVC3.cs class.

I can change the template to customise the repository that is created but I am at a bit of a loss as to how I can causes the  template to add content to a separate file.

Anyone done anything similar? Also I guess splitting the repository and its interface into seperate files would be handy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to create a different class file from the original T4 template, I think it's better if you create a new template for this purpose. If you want to save a file in a tempalte, you can create the file using Syste.IO library :

```
<#@ import namespace=“System.IO” #>

<#+
  void SaveOutput(string outputFileName)
  {
      string templateDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile);
      string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(templateDirectory, outputFileName);
      File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath, GetMyContent()); 
  }
#>
<#+
  string GetMyContent()
  {
      // clean the environment 
      this.GenerationEnvironment.Remove(0, this.GenerationEnvironment.Length);
      #>
        This is my content
      <#+
      // return new content
      return this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString(); 
  }
#>
```

You need to develope your `GetMyContent()` to fill the output file with the correct content. In this example `GetMyContent` cleans the environment every time, so remember to use the SaveOutput method after all the other files are created.

Comment: That should help with the splitting the repository file. I also want to add code into an existing class file as part of scaffolding the repository with MVC Scaffolding template. Any ideas there?

Comment: @GraemeMiller You can try to modify the ControllerWithRepository.cs.t4 file (make a backup copy before) placed under the packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.4.0 directory in the your project. You can add the SaveOutput function and your new content.